# if i want to receive data from the server the app does not go to the URLSession if debug hem then skip the URLSession and i don't know why

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, httprequest

This is the Json object which I should receive

[
{
"id": "18",
"profileName": "testProfiel24"
},
{
"id": "19",
"profileName": "testProfiel25"
},
{
"id": "1021",
"profileName": "testProfiel26"
},
{
"id": "1022",
"profileName": "testProfiel27"
},
{
"id": "1023",
"profileName": "testProfiel28"
}
]

This the `function` that I send, I used my api url to send an api call

```swift
    func getData(){
        
        let getToken : String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken")
```

I add a value of the token to the url  and with the print line I get the link

```swift
        let url = URL(string: "http://....../profile/load")!
        let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: getToken!)]
        let newUrl = url.appending(queryItems)!
        print(newUrl)
```

The I make a URLSession with the new URL
but when hi goed to make dataTask. hi skips every things and goes to
resume()

```swift
         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newUrl, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        
                    guard let data = data,error == nil else{
                        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                        return
                    }
        
                    var result : Profile?
        
                    do{
                        result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: data)
                    }catch{
        
                        print("failed to convert\(error.localizedDescription)")
        
                    }
        
                    guard let json = result else{
                        return
                    }
        
                    print(json.id)
                    print(json.profileName)
                }).resume()
```

with the debug mode I get this value of dataTask =
LocalDataTask <1F6380AD-5D01-490D-BA4A-94A7FD893531>.<2>

But I don't receive any data for the server because hi skips it

This the code to add a key and a value to the link and it works good

```swift
extension URL {

    func appending(_ queryItems: [URLQueryItem]) -> URL? {
        guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {

            return nil
        }

        urlComponents.queryItems = (urlComponents.queryItems ?? []) + queryItems


        return urlComponents.url
    }
}
```

This the data that should receive for the server

```swift
struct Profile : Decodable {
    let id, profileName : String
    
}
```

Comment: There might be a couple issues here. 1. You don't want to pass a confidential access token in the query parameter via "http". In fact, iOS would not allow you "http" per default. See [ATS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections) for more info about this topic. Basically, you should always use "https" for your production app, and you may configure certain settings in your plist file to disable security settings in _development only_.
Also set a break point into the else path of the guard statement, to break at errors to get more info.